# Generate word document file from template having .dot file template

Tags: templates, ms-word

I am working on a requirement where I have to  generate word document file from template having .dot extension.

Please guide me regarding the same.

Comment: @rene I had a question on `dot` from the Graphviz package. Before asking it I wanted to check if it'd been asked on SO. Search by the `[dot]` returned significant amount of irrelevant questions (mostly on regexes, file paths, etc), so I just removed the tag from these questions. Not sure if I need to ask a question on metaSO for this.

Answer (score 0):

From within a document:

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim newDocument As Document
    Set newDocument = Documents.Add("d:\mySourceTemplate.dot")
End Sub
```